# Open File during Installation

Tags: nsis

I am using NSIS to create installer. Also I need to install other program (I have his installation file). How add second installer to automatically run it during first installation?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to run the file (which must be first extracted to some directory,. e.g. $TEMP) with

```
ExecShell "open" "$INSTDIR\app.exe"
```

or with

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\someprogram.exe"' $0
```

if you want to wait for program to finish.

Also consider many possibilities: whether the app should be run with some parameter, in Silent mode or elevated with admin rights or run as original user...